# How can I reattach my steam outlet pod?

Tags: bathtub, bathroom-fixtures, steam

I have a shower tub steam combo of an unknown brand, installed by the previous owner, and I accidentally hit the steam outlet pod, which came off.

[image: the steam outlet pod]

[image: the hole]

The pipe it was attached to also came off :

[image: the no longer attached pipe]

How can I fix this mess ?

Comment: Where is the actual steam unit? you should be able to get a brand name off it. you're gonna have to get those plastic pieces out  and take them to a plumbing supply store.....

Comment: Educated guess is that the tub is a Jacuzzi brand tub, There are a few parts suppliers online. Working in that space is not easy.

Comment: Looks as though it was plumbed with standard PVC, which I don't think is rated for steam, so it got brittle and broke. The steam generators I have seen all say that the plumbing must be copper or brass only.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got a generic replacement that had the same dimensions from an online shop.

I didn't change the plastic elbow fitting, because this part wasn't damaged.